# Magento 2 : How to suffle the products by sort on list page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-collection, product-sorting

I want to snuffle the products on list page but unable to do that. Here is the code.

> app/code/Am/Suffle/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Am_Suffle_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Config" sortOrder="10" type="Am\Suffle\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Am_Suffle_Magictoolbar_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_ProductList_Toolbar" sortOrder="10" type="Am\Suffle\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Am/Suffle/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php 

namespace Am\Suffle\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config
{

    /**
     * Adding custom options and changing labels
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param [] $options
     * @return []
     */

    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $subject,
        $options
    ) {

        //New sorting options
        $customOption['ai_magic'] = __(' Magic');

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Am/Suffle/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Am\Suffle\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{

    /**
     * Plugin
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
        $entity_ids =  array();
        foreach($collection as $product){
            $entity_ids[] = $product->getId();
        }

        shuffle($entity_ids);
        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'ai_magic') {
                // $subject->getCollection()->clear();
                $collection->clear();
                // $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $entity_ids)
;
                $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $entity_ids).')'));
            } 
        }

        return $subject;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code:**

> app/code/Am/Suffle/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Am\Suffle\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'ai_magic') {
                $subject->getCollection()
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)
                    ->orderRand();
            }
        }

        return $subject;
    }   
}
```

**Note:**
To implement random products functionality on the category page refresh, you need to disable FPC cache.

- php bin/magento cache:disable full_page

Please note that, this is temporary solution, will update answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please let me know why we can not use that order filter ? I have checked with M1.9, it worked fine.